# Who's Using Cairngorm 2.2 with Imported Web Services?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, flexbuilder, cairngorm

I'm very new to Cairngorm, so apologies for what's probably a simple question:

I'm working with a number of WCF services imported into Flex Builder 3 (via Data > Manage Web Services), and I'm wondering how to expose those services to the ServiceLocator in Cairngorm.  From what I've read so far, it looks like Cairngorm prefers the services be defined in Services.mxml (or somehow in MXML), but that won't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an app right now where Services.mxml is driving me nuts... calls are just not being made. I've read the blog posts that describe solutions to this issue but it's a recurring, nagging problem so I want to find a more reliable approach. I believe that you could simply replace the code in your Delegate where you retrieve the reference to the web service

```
this.service = ServiceLocator.getInstance().getWebService("web service name here");
```

to something like this:

```
this.service = generated.webservices.MyService();
```

I'm hoping that, after that, the rest should be straight forward. I'm planning to do some testing tonight so I'll let you know how it goes.